# Задать стиль элементу, до загрузки.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть конструкция:

```
<script>
//здесь необходимо задать стиль элементу div к примеру color:#fff
</script>
<div class="some_div"></div>
```

**P.S.** Убедительная просьба воздержаться от ответов типа, лучше поменять структуру, так никто не делает. варианты типа `document.write('<style></style>');` и `$(document).ready()` тоже не подходят.

Comment: Пахнет костылем... В css задать стили никак?

Comment: а в чем у вас загвоздка, див при загрузке страницы выглядит не так и нет возможности ждать загрузки дом чтобы поменять его стиль?

Comment: стиль присваивается по условию, смысл в том, что в скрипте вызывается функция к примеру `change_div(".some_div")` в качестве селектора в параметрах, и все дивы с нужным селектором приобретают определенные свойства. можно и в стилях прописать и подгружать но хотелось бы найти элегантное решение по принципу `live` в jQuery.

Comment: @makregistr если не получится придется ждать, но интуиция подсказывает, что должно быть решение. плюс возможна подгрузка аяксом новых дивов, тогда жди не жди после каждого запроса придется обновлять стили.

Comment: можно определить какой-то дефолтный предварительный стиль и потом его обновлять в зависимости от дальнейших манипуляциях или прятать дивы пока они не обновятся

Comment: Подумайте, можно ли при первой загрузки страницы высчитывать какие стили применить на сервере?

Comment: @makregistr как вариант, добавлять класс к диву с предопределенными стилями, минус в том что надо будет подгружать css дополнительный. думаю надо попробовать копать в сторону stylesheets js

Comment: Вопрос выглядит примерно так - как, не имея переменной, с ней работать. В общем случае ответ элементарно прост - НИКАК, вы все-равно ждете загрузки, каким образом - вопрос 10ый.

PS: хотите изменить стиль "до загрузки"? css для этого есть, не? -_-

Comment: @AlexWindHope вопрос больше звучит как "какие есть альтернативные способы динамически задать стиль используя js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сама ситуация нелепа. Вот вам нелепое решение:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() { $('.some_div').css('color', '#fff'); }, 10000);
    // таймуат - примерное время загрузки нужных элементов
</script>
<div class="some_div"></div>
```

Решения на основе `.load` не подойдут, ибо это событие не "всплывает" ни в одном браузере.

Comment: да согласен нелепая, связано это с тем что хочется найти альтернативные решения очевидному document.write(), искренне надеюсь, что получится.

Answer (score 1):

Решение: Любая задача решается штатными методами. Вопрос: Что мешает выставить стиль после инициализации дива ? Может грамотно продумывать архитектуру скрипта и есть решение ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще одно нелепое решение:

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
    $('.some_div').css('color','#F00');
}, 1);
</script>
<div class="some_div">111</div>
<div class="some_div">222</div>
<div class="some_div">333</div>
```

Comment: Да, если еще использовать какой-нибудь флаг с последующим `clearInterval` - вполне замечательно. Как жалко, что нельзя указать в качестве интервала 0.1 или 0.01!

Comment: Дык, а зачем тормозить? Пусть себе раскрашивает div-ы до потери пульса ))

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно как это до загрузки, если честно. Это ж все будет исполнятся конкретно браузером. И как Вы это хотите сделать без jQuery(document).ready() то же не очень понятно. Если я хоть отдаленно понял Ваш вопрос, то можно поступить так:

```
<script>

//--------
// Здесь блок необходимых настроек и изменений стилей
jQuery('.some_class').css('color','red');
// и т.д.
//--------

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
// Как ни крути, но ready нужно, что бы отделить момент 
// полной и неполной загрузки документа
// Далее будем привязывать события и т.д., прим:
jQuery('.some_class').click(function(){
console.log('Console echo by some_class');
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: без ready делается просто - вставляется скрипт сразу после загрузки всех нужных дивов с .some_class, они уже есть на странице и скрипт их найдет, остальные нас не интересуют. Правда этот метод костыльный и не удобный.